# Giving C# Tuples order extension methods or similar

Tags: c#, tuples

```
public static class tuple_extentions
{
    public static Vector2 mul(this Tuple<Vector2 v, float f>)
    {
        return v * f;
    }
}

public void main()
{
    Tuple.Create(new Vector2(4, 3), 2).mul(); // works
    Tuple.Create(2, new Vector2(4, 3)).mul(); // doesn't work
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this or something similar with multiple definitions not being required and still working with Intelisence, with or without extensions and the Tuple class.

3 such parameters for example would require up to 6 definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to make a general purpose extension method that will work with all `Tuple` combinations.  C# has no such facility.  A different extension must be given for every `Tuple` type that you want it to work on

Comment: I know this is an old response, but do we currently have any proposal for variable arity (like variadic templates in C++) that you could link to? This would be such an incredibly powerful feature to have that I imagine someone has at least started investigating it for C# vNext or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can't abstract over the arity of tuples, unfortunately. To get this functionality you need some sort of heterogenous list. http://jeff.cutsinger.org/blarg/2011/03/27/heterogeneous-lists.html has a nice set up to expand upon.